# Selniuem webdriver java(Drag and Drop issue)

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, drag-and-drop

I have added robot class to drag from left to right in the frame but it is not working I also use action builder drag and drop it is not working somehow I use robot class so it clicks on the header but does not do drag and drop
Here is my code :

```
        WebDriverWait waitDrag = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(30));
    waitDrag.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"root\"]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div[1]/div")));
    WebElement fromWebElement =driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"root\"]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div[1]/div"));
    WebElement toWebElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class=\"react-flow__pane\"]"));

    Point coordinates1 = fromWebElement.getLocation();
    Point coordinates2 = toWebElement.getLocation();

    Robot robot = new Robot();

    robot.mouseMove(coordinates1.getX(), coordinates1.getY());
    robot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
    robot.mouseMove(coordinates2.getX(), coordinates2.getY());
    robot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
    Thread.sleep(2000);
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! What is the website that you are trying this on? Please share the website link if it is ok to do so

Comment: Check out this [https://stackoverflow.com/a/72335980/11863448]